# position absolute top:0, bottom: 0, right:0, left:0 and parent paddings

Tags: reactjs, react-native, flexbox, position, absolute

position absolute with all its properties in 0 makes the child element expand in the parent element, and if I put a padding in the parent element without a height the child with the position absolute cover until the of the parent padding, my theory is right or I am forgotting something here?there could be another different case?

```
import React from 'react';
import {View, StyleSheet} from 'react-native';
import Video from 'react-native-video';

export default function Reproductor(props) {
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <View style={styles.videoContainer}>
        <Video
          source={{
            uri:
              'http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/gtv-videos-bucket/sample/BigBuckBunny.mp4',
          }}
          resizeMode="cover"
          style={styles.video}
        />
      </View>
    </View>
  );
}
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    height: 250,

    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
  videoContainer: {
    width: '90%',
    paddingTop: '56.25%',

    borderRadius: 20,
    overflow: 'hidden',
    borderWidth: 3,
    backgroundColor: 'black',
  },
  video: {
    position: 'absolute',
    top: 0,
    left: 0,
    bottom: 0,
    right: 0,
  },
});
```

the child (video) covers the padding

Comment: position absolute with all its properties in 0 is similar to 100% width and 100% height. if you want the ```styles.video``` follows ```styles.videoContainer```, make sure the height and width are the same

Answer (score 2):

> An **absolutely positioned** element is an element whose computed
>   position value is absolute or fixed. The **top**, **right**,
>   **bottom**, and **left** properties specify offsets from the **edges of the element's containing block**.
>   https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position

position `absolute` related to the edges of the parent element (= ignores parent padding/border).

```html
<div style="padding: 50px; background: red; color: white; position:relative;">
  <div style="border: 1px solid white; height: 50px;"></div>
  <div style="position: absolute; background: blue; top:0; left:0; color: white;">child</div>
</div>
```

`top: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0;` is the way to set overlay:

**Example:** https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_overlay.asp

```html
<div style="padding: 50px; background: red; color: white; position:relative;">
  <div style="border: 1px solid white;">div</div>
  <div style="position: absolute; background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5); top:0px; left:0px; right: 0; bottom: 0; color: white;">overlay</div>
</div>
```

Add space by `top: 10px;` for example (or `em` `%` and so on)

```html
<div style="padding: 50px; background: red; color: white; position:relative;">
  <div style="border: 1px solid white;">Parent</div>
  <div style="position: absolute; background: blue; top:10px; left:10px; color: white;">child</div>
</div>
```

Or add a `margin` for the absolute element:

```html
<div style="padding: 50px; background: red; color: white; position:relative;">
  <div style="border: 1px solid white;">Parent</div>
  <div style="position: absolute; background: blue; top:0px; left:0px; color: white;margin: 10px;">margin: 10px around</div>
</div>
```

You find more tricks/ideas but these are the basics ideas.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you I understand, but you said that it cover padding and border (position absolute related to the edges of the parent element (= ignores parent padding/border).), and I try to cover the border too but it just ignore the padding not the border, what is my mistake here?

```
export default function MainScreen(props) {
  return (

      <View style={style.container}>
        <View style={style.element} />
      </View>

  );
}
const style = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    borderWidth: 3,
    padding: 40,
    alignSelf: 'center',
    width: 200,
    height: 200,
    backgroundColor: 'grey',
  },
  element: {
    position: 'absolute',
    top: 0,
    bottom: 0,
    left: 0,
    right: 0,
    width: 100,
    height: 100,
    backgroundColor: 'purple',
  },
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
            <style>#SCcont13372{width: 100%;padding-top: 56.25%;position: relative;}#SCgFrame13372 {position: absolute;top: 0;left: 0;bottom: 0;right: 0;}</style>
            <div id="SCcont13372">
              <iframe id="SCgFrame13372" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="" mozallowfullscreen="" webkitallowfullscreen="" hspace="0" vspace="0" scrolling="none" src="https://slotcatalog.com/pt/slots/Baccarat-Deluxe-PG-Soft?ajax=1&blck=demo-widget" width="100%" height="100%"></iframe>
            </div>
```